# Array Type expected found on onBindViewHolder?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to show a list which has image at left side and a Title at right side using RecyclerView.

Through `for` loop, i added Title and image in a ArrayList

```
String[] mtitles = {"Title","Title","Title","Title","Title","Title","Title","Title","Title","Title"};
int[] mimages = {R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher};

 List<Feed> items = new ArrayList<Feed>();
    Feed feed = new Feed();
    for (int i=0;i<mtitles.length;i++)

    {
        feed.setImage(mimages[i]);
        feed.setTitle(mtitles[i]);
        items.add(feed);
    }

    adapter = new MyAdapter(items);
```

This is my Feed.class

```
public class Feed {

    String title;
    int image;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

MyAdapter.class

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public List<Feed> items;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public ImageView icon;
        public TextView title;

        public ViewHolder(View v)
        {
            super(v);
            icon = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView);


        }

    }


    public MyAdapter(List<Feed> items)
    {
        this.items=items;
    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.icon.setImageResource(items[position]); // Problem here

    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }
}
```

On this line,

```
 holder.icon.setImageResource(items[position]);
```

i'm getting error.

```
 Array type expected;found.
```

Screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Is that really what it says?

Comment: Checkout my question. I updated the screenshot.

Comment: Why did you say your error is `Array type expected; found.` if the error is `Array type expected; found: 'java.util.List<com.example.yuvaraj.myapplication.Feed>`? (Honestly curious about your thought process here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
holder.icon.setImageResource(items.get(position).getImage());
```

Because `items` is `List` of `Feed` class objects instead of `Array` .

Comment: Thanks, it displayed the list. But, it applying the last title and image to the entire list. I mean, it display `Title one` text for all row not taking individual texts.

Comment: @user3289108: ok move `Feed feed = new Feed();` line inside `for loop`. probably it will work..:)

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31355629/how-to-access-invidual-json-objects-from-a-json-array

Answer (score 1):

The `[]` indexing notation is only for arrays. `List`s have a `get` method: `items.get(position)`

Answer (score -1):

make an edit like this:

public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

```
            tempValue=null; // this is an object of Feed class
            tempValue = ( Feed ) items.get( position );

    holder.icon.setImageResource(tempValue.getImage()); // try thishere

}
```