# How to access invidual json objects from a json array?

Tags: android, json

I have the following response, and I want to display all `eqid`'s in invidual `TextView`'s, but I don't know how to achive this, 
below is my snippet code and response to get data from the server and display in textview.
Can anyone help me with this?

```
{
  "earthquakes":[
    {
      "eqid":"c0001xgp",

    },
    {
      "eqid":"c000905e",

    },
    {
      "eqid":"2007hear",

    },
    {
      "eqid":"c00090da",

    },
    {
      "eqid":"2007aqbk",

    },
    {
      "eqid":"2007hec6",

    },
    {
      "eqid":"a00043nx",

    },
    {
      "eqid":"2010utc5",

    },

  ]
}
```

Code

```
   ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
    jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(USER_URL, ServiceHandler.GET);
    Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

    try{
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
        JSONArray items = json.getJSONArray("product");

        parent_layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl);
        for(int i =0; i<items.length(); i++){



            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setText(items.getJSONObject(i).getString(USER_NAME));

            parent_layout.addView(textView);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
try{
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonstr);
    JSONArray items = json.getJSONArray("earthquakes");

    for(int i =0; i<items.length(); i++){
        TextView t=new TextView(context);
        t.setText(items.getJSONObject(i).getString('eqid'));
        ParentLayout.addView(t);
    }
}catch(JSONException e){
    e.printStacktrace();
}
```

Comment: see my edited code in question..i dont have any error..but response is not displaying

Comment: as you have used Relative layout your textview will be overlapping on each other...Try Linear layout or add attributes like layoutToLeftOf or above or below and like that....

Answer (score 1):

You have a single JSON object which contains a Single JSON array. So you first retrieve the array from the object and then you are able to loop over it to retrieve all the items. In below code I assume you have the destined `TextView` objects in an array.

```
try{
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonstr);
    JSONArray items = json.getJSONArray("earthquakes");

    for(int i =0; i<items.length(); i++){
        textViews[i].setText(items.getJSONObject(i).getString('eqid'));
    }
}catch(JSONException e){
    e.printStacktrace();
}
```

Comment: can you tell one things??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917214/change-background-colour-of-current-listview-item-in-adapter-getview-method....in this question they chagne color..can i add buttons alternatvly

Comment: That would be a separate question. Questions should stay on topic.

Comment: array type expected found android widget textview..it shows

Comment: @Roman In my answer I state that I assume that the destined `TextView` objects are in an array and can therefore be referenced like `textViews[i]` in the loop. If the `textView` variable does not reference a `TextView` array you will get this error. I assume you know yourself where to find the `TextViews` you want to put the data.

Comment: i have multiple textviews..and i want to set indvidual id in individual textviews

Comment: Use a `LinearLayout` to display newly created `TextViews` or add additional properties. `RelativeLayout` displays everything top left if you do not specify the relative positions between views.